# Appending a key value pair to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272051/appending-a-key-value-pair-to-a-json-object). However, I want to add a property to an object but I don't know the name of that property. The scenario is that I have some users connecting to a namespace in my `socket.io app`, when a user connects a random `socket.id` is generated to be able to differentiate that user from the rest of the users, when the user connects they also send their gender to the server (via `socket.emit`), now I want to create an object that keeps track of the users' socket ids and genders.

```
var users = {};               // create empty object 
var specialID = socket.id;    // get user's socketid
var gender;                   // suppose gender contains their gender (male or female)
```

now I tried

```
users.specialID = gender;
```

but that changes the `specialID` property of the users object every single time a user connects. It doesn't add a new property/value pair (who's property is the `specialID` (`socket.id`) and who's value is the gender of the user). It sounds kind of stupid but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
users['your key'] = gender;
```