# Take a Key:Object pair and append to another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, key-value

I have two javascript Objects. I want to take a *key:Object* pair from the first and put it into the second.

```
var first  = { a:1, b:2, c:{c1:11, c2:22, c3:33} }   
var second = { d:3, e:4 }
```

How can I obtain a third `object` such as this?

```
{ d:3, e:4, c:{c1:11, c2:22, c3:33} }
```

Is this the most elegant solution?

```
var third = second
third.c=first.c
```

I would like to avoid repeating the `.c`, something like **"take `first.c` and append both key and value to the second object",**

This solution supposes that you have key and value separated: [Appending a key value pair to a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272051/appending-a-key-value-pair-to-a-json-object) 
and this one [Appending a key value pair to a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912657/appending-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object) adds in fact a new key which does not belong to another object.

Comment: "elegant" is in the eye of the beholder, and is thus not on topic. I'm not sure what's wrong with "repeating the `.c`", since that's the specific property you want. At some point, you're going to need to specify it, one way or another.

Comment: "I would like to avoid repeating the .c, something like "take first.c and append both key and value to the second object"" - Not sure why you don't want to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in JavaScript there are several options to set a property to an object:

1. Using simple `.` or `[]` notations, is the easiest and the most common way.
2. Using [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method.
3. Using [**Object.defineProperty()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [**Object.defineProperties()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) methods.

Apart from the fact that the third option `defineProperty()`/`defineProperties()` give you the hand to customize these extra properties with **descriptors** such as `configurable`, `enumerable` and `writable` or `get` and `set` accessors, all these options will do the same thing and extend the òbject`with a new`property`.

So basically there's no much *elegant* or most suitable way to use, it all depends on the situation.

---

In your specific case to avoid doing it in two lines:

```
var third = second
third.c=first.c
```

You can better use `Object.assign()` like this:

```
var third = Object.assign({}, second, { c: first.c });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use, which mutates the object

```
Object.assign(second, { c: first.c });
```

this one does not mutate the object

```
var third = Object.assign({}, second, { c: first.c });
```

or spread operator (you need to transpile it using Babel).

```
second = { ...second, { c: first.c });
```

Comment: the first mutates `second` and the second does not work with objects in ES6.

Comment: You are right. I'm used to use transpiler to use the spread operator. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cousl use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and use a new object as result.

```js
var first  = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { c1: 11, c2: 22, c3: 33 } },
    second = { d: 3, e: 4 },
    third = Object.assign({}, second, { c: first.c });

console.log(third);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code, namely the [object property spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/#example-rest-properties):

```
var third = {...second, c: first.c}; // ESNEXT
```

This is currently a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) considered for inclusion into the next JavaScript standard. For now, use Babel for backwards compatibility: [Try it out.](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20first%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A1%2C%20b%3A2%2C%20c%3A%7Bc1%3A11%2C%20c2%3A22%2C%20c3%3A33%7D%20%7D%20%0Avar%20second%20%3D%20%7B%20d%3A3%2C%20e%3A4%20%7D%0Avar%20third%20%3D%20%7B...second%2C%20c%3A%20first.c%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20ES2016%0Aconsole.log(third)%3B)

Comment: interesting, but it does not work in `node` 7.10 console

Comment: @leonardvertighel Might be in node 8 nightly: http://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3---object-rest-properties

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy by reference, the easiest way is to do what you did.

```
var third = second
third.c=first.c
```

But this will also make second have a 'c' property on it.
For a clean object, one way would be to do

```
var third = Object.assign({}, first, second);
delete first.a
delete first.b
```

Or you could do something like this

```
var third = Object.assign({}, second)
third.c = Object.assign({}, first.c)
```